# Move CloseableHttpResponse inside nested try with resources

Tags: java, httpresponse, apache-httpclient-4.x, try-with-resources, closeablehttpresponse

I have the following code using try with resources with `CloseableHttpResponse`

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().build()){    
    //code...
    response = httpClient.execute(target, post);
    String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());   
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Failed sending request", e);
} finally {
    if (response != null) {
        try {
            response.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Failed releasing response", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Can I safely replace with nested try with resources:

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().build()){
    URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url);
    HttpHost target = new HttpHost(uriBuilder.getHost(), uriBuilder.getPort(), uriBuilder.getScheme());
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uriBuilder.build());
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(target, post)) {
        String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());   
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Failed sending request", e);
}
```

Or is it better to use a single try with resources block:

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().build();
    CloseableHttpResponse response = getResponse(httpClient, url)) {
```

Sometime refactoring to single block is problematic, so I wanted to know the a nested/additional block is a valid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpClient never returns a null `HttpResponse` object. The first construct is simply not useful.  Both the second and the third constructs are perfectly valid

Comment: Is there an issue with using nested/additional try-with-resources block ?

Comment: No, there is not. However generally one should not create a new instance of HttpClient for each and every request. It is _extremely_ wasteful and inefficient.

Comment: Are you referring using `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` 
 as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959772/spring-configurable-high-performance-metered-http-client-instances

Comment: The connection pool with persistent connections is certainly one thing that one should not just throw away, but also other expensive operations such SSL/TLS context initialization should ideally only be done one at run-time

Comment: Is your comment about SSL relevant also for 1 request per hour(s)?

Comment: Probably not, but why not keeping and re-using HttpClient instance for all subsequent requests?

Comment: @ok2c I know this is quite old but can you please confirm that you meant that the CloseableHttpResponse response can not be null, also similarly is it correct that StatusLine in the response can never be null?

Comment: @RaRa I confirm. HttpClient 4.x and 5.x never return response messages in an inconsistent / invalid state